# Is this argument about an invertible matrix valid?

Tags: linear-algebra

The exercise is

> Explain why an invertible matrix $\bf A$ has to be a square matrix.

The explanation from the book:

> An invertible matrix $\bf A$ has to be a square matrix because we know
>   it has an inverse, say $\bf B$, which satisfies $\bf AB = BA = I$ . The rows
>   and columns of matrix A must be equal because both multiplications
>   $\bf AB$ and $\bf BA$ are possible.

So if I get it correctly, the author's main argument is following: the matrix $\bf A$ must be square because otherwise there won't be matrix $\bf B$ such that multiplications $\bf AB, BA$ are both valid.

Well, consider arbitrary $n$ by $m$ matrix $\bf A$ ($n ≠ m$) and arbitrary $m$ by $n$ matrix $\bf B$. If I get it correctly, multiplications $\bf AB$ and $\bf BA$ are both valid in this case, but the number of rows and columns *are not equal*.

**Questions:**

1. Is the author's argument correct?
2. If it is not, is there a better way to explain why $\bf A$ has to be a square matrix (given that it is invertible)?

Comment: In your example, what would be the dimensions of $\mathbf{AB}$ and $\mathbf{BA}$? Can they ever be equal?

Comment: You can see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse

Comment: I think the author's reason for excluding your case (where $A$ is $m \times n$ and $B$ is $n \times m$) is that we can no longer have the $AB = BA$ part of $AB = BA = I$, since $AB$ and $BA$ would be different sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your question before the two questions:

> If $A$ is $n\times m$ and $B$ is $m \times n$, both products are defined, but $A B$ is $n \times n$ and $B A$ is $m \times m$ hence they can't be equal.

As noted in the comments there are notions of [generalised inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse), such as the [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse), which can be defined for non-square matrices.

1. The author's argument is correct.
2. Another argument could be the determinant. If you know (or define) that a matrix is invertible iff its determinant is nonzero, you can argue that the determinant is only defined for square matrices, but I prefer the author's argument.